# Magento CE 1.7.0.2 - Editing order not canceling original

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm not sure exactly what change would of caused the issue where if I edit a processing order and place new one it does not cancel the original one. Looked on Google and StackOverflow for existing solution but came up empty really.

**Steps to Reproduce (Scenario):**

1. You need to edit an order because customer forgot to add an item to it so I click "Edit" on that order which is in "Processing" status
2. Place the order
3. Looking at the Sales->orders list I can see that the original order is in Processing status still IN ERROR. The new order has same order# with "-1" appended at end which is good

So, I was wondering if anyone else has experienced such an issue. It used to cancel the original order after you placed it. The warning JS message that pops up after clicking "Edit" says it would place new order and mark current as Canceled so something is wrong. Nothing seems out of the ordinary in my config.

EDIT: Guess nobody has experienced an issue such as this. I can't think of anything that would cause this. Since this post I've upgraded Magento to CE 1.7.0.2.

Thanks,

George

EDIT: Screenshot attached:

[image: screenshot showing view order on Magento]

Comment: Still not sure where this problem came from however... the problem is no longer present magically... I expect its return but I am unclear on why or where to look to fix it. At least it is a low priority issue as of this writing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't cancel order that is already **processing ( invoiced ) / Shipped / Complete** !!

You only can cancel order in **NEW State**

In your case you had an invoiced order and you want to do re-order :-

- Press Edit and go ahead with the new Orders ( The order will be suffixed by -1/-2 because this means this order linked/related to the previous order )
- Go the original order and Refund it complete ( it will be in closed state / status )

You need to understand the work flow of the order and the operations you can take on the order in **EACH STATE**

Comment: Thanks Meabed. Looks like if you do a CC order it will go to Processing and therefore when doing an edit it will not cancel the original order as designed in Magento. The only orders that go to "new" are Purchase Orders. Tried getting the CC to work as "new" when orders placed but didn't work. This is fine. We are doing stuff against Magento's practice because we added ability to change order directly on the Sales->Order view page. This has been working for our client and they needed this ability to change right away. I'll post screenshot to my original post.

Comment: Thanks for your time Meabed. Congrats on the bounty!

Comment: Yes when you do an order with credit card usually it gets invoiced because you already got the money from the customer and you must keep record of that !! and when you do cancel you have to do proper REFUND so you also have track of the transaction and its reverse ! but orders in NEW state usually not paid or cash on delivery so you can cancel it normally because it has nothing related to it. The process overall make sense if you got what i mean :)

Comment: Yes, I understand. The orders are tracked. Refunds are never issued on Magento for this client. If a refund is issued it is done directly through Authorize.net.